# VLCKit: VLCMediaPlayer move to time

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, libvlc

I want to scroll a video to a specific time.
For example I have an one minute video with a slider and I want to change the playing position.

```
- (IBAction)itemSlider:(UISlider *)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    if ([event.allTouches anyObject].phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
    {
        VLCTime *newTime = [VLCTime timeWithNumber:@(sender.value/1000)]; //convert milliseconds to seconds

        [mediaplayer.media setLength:newTime]; //tried to set time
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no "seek" or "jump" or "setTime:" or anything equivalent in `VLCMediaPlayer`, as we can find in a wrapper: https://github.com/larrytin/VLCKit/blob/master/Sources/VLCMediaPlayer.m ?

Comment: @Larme 
So is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New time I must set to all `mediaplayer player` object, not only to `media` object.

```
[mediaplayer setTime:newTime];
```

Comment: you cannot seek more than once, it's a bug in the VLCPlayer, see the issue here: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/issues/157

Comment: Hello @Mudassir, oh it was so long time ago. But from my comment, I see that it was possible for the whole player and not for the "media" item.
Also, just checked other links: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/-/issues/593
Here mentioned that "setTime" function should be available like a setter.